# stopping web page jumping back to top after function call

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using a ViewBag to pass a List into a View. I am then displaying each string in the list as a href one by one using a foreach over the List. I have a function which allows a user to click on each href to remove it from the list. The problem is, when a user clicks a href to remove it from the list and from the view, the web page jumps back to the top. Is there any way I can stop this? e.g. when a user clicks to remove a href string from the list, the page stays where it is

**edit.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group" style="min-height: 100px">
    <div class="col-md-10" style="min-height: 100px">
        <hr />
        <p><strong>Flagged Questions</strong></p>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.FLagList)
        {
        <div>
            <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)">@item</a>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**function**

```
<script>
    function onDelete(elm, id) {
    // Do something with id
    console.log(id)
    elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the `href attribute from the anchor tag
and then you can give custom css for the anchor to restore the missed styles due to removing the href att.

```html
 <a class='custom-link' onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)">@item</a>
```

```css
.custom-link:link {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.custom-link:visited {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.custom-link:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.custom-link:active {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks a lot Safi

Answer (score 1):

What happens is after your function is executed, the link with `href="#"` is triggered. Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent that from happening.

```js
function myFunction(event, val) {
  console.log(val);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(event, 'myValue')">Click me</a>
```

Comment: what about the razor function this is already being called at his onclick attribute. this means replacing his razor code. the best practice would be removing the href att and restoring the link styles by writing custom classes in css

Comment: @Martin Buezas I am not too sure what I would do with the razor function then but thanks a lot for the reply

Comment: well, after reviewing, i noticed that his function isn't razor, it is javascript, so adding an event parameter would work, nevertheless, fundamentally there isn't a need for the href attribute to be there at all. so the best practice is to totally remove the attribute instead of preventing its default

Comment: That way you end up with unnecesary extra CSS to keep your hover/active styles. The best practice is to prevent default. Alternatively you can just return false in your function. A third option is to add `javascript:void(0)` as your href value